# Recursion with termination condition Java

Tags: java, recursion

I'm teaching myself about recursive calling of methods in java. I'm constantly getting `StackOverFlowError`on my implementation:

```
    public class LimitedRecursion {
      public void m(int limit) {
        if (limit == 0) {
          System.out.println("finished2");
        }
        m(limit - 1);
      }
     }
```

i have set the limit to 42 in the main. Can someone point me to the right direction on this? Its supposed to terminate once `limit == 0`

Comment: `StackOverFlowError` indicates that you have a infinite loop.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This doesn't finish the recursion, since you don't exit the method when the condition is met, and you still make the next recursive call (`m(limit - 1);`) :

```
    if (limit == 0) {
      System.out.println("finished2");
    }
    m(limit - 1);
```

This will end the recursion :

```
    if (limit == 0) {
      System.out.println("finished2");
      return;
    }
    m(limit - 1);
```

Comment: Thanks buddy. I'll accept this answer in a few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

The correct recursion can be :

```
    public class LimitedRecursion {
public void m(int limit) {
    if (limit == 0) {
        System.out.println("finished2");
    } else {
        m(limit - 1);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, Add a `return statement`

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(m(5));
    }

    public static String m(int limit) {
        if (limit == 0) {
            return "finished";
        }
        return m(limit - 1);
    }
```

**output**

```
finished
```